# Making 10+ user accounts on Mac

Tags: mac, user-accounts

I'm trying to find a way to find a way to create 10+ user accounts easily. Would I use a terminal shell, applescript or another automation tool?

Comment: What have you found so far? Why didn't it work for you?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/226073/how-do-i-create-user-accounts-from-the-terminal-in-mac-os-x-10-11

Comment: I've looked around there isn't much about creating many users on a mac. Some youtube videos just showed how to create one user the default way and that is not what i'm looking for since that would take alot of time to do each user that way. When I search on the web most of the websites are old and confusing.